# Module batch copy not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, batch

I often use the batch tool to copy and set the correct language for my categories, articles and menu items when building a multi-lingual website.

But when I try the same thing with modules, the language is set correctly, but on the ORIGINAL module, and no copy is created.

I know I can use the "Duplicate" button, but the copies are all un-published, and I have to edit each of them to set the correct language.

What am I missing here?

[image: Batch copy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is part of the text below the title:

> When copying and not changing position, it is nevertheless necessary to select 'Keep Original Position' in the dropdown

That means you have to select "Keep Original Position" in the "Set Position" dropdown. It's easy to miss because other elements like category and articles does have this option.

The copied modules will still be set to "Unpublished", but the language will be correctly set.

Hope that helps.